# Python Shell with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, python, shell

I run a test.js with:

```
var power_meter = require('./power-meter');
var pm = new power_meter.PowerMeter();

function a() {
  var power_instant = 123;
  pm.broadcast(power_instant);
  setTimeout(a, 249);
}

a();
```

The Output is 
123
123
...

Now i want to import a value from a python script with python-shell with:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell('7powerx.py');
var power_meter = require('./power-meter');
var pm = new power_meter.PowerMeter();

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {

  console.log(message);
  var power_instant = message;
  pm.broadcast (power_instant);
  });

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit



// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
  pyshell.end(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

I have tried to set the "setTimeout(a, 249);"
a();

in any place but without any success.
The script started and do an output after circa 5 minutes, but then stops again and after a time it works again for a moment.
I need to place the "setTimeout" but no idea where.

Any idea?

Update.
I have in my pythonScript a time function, when i set this to 0.0 it works, but my Raspberry PI collapse. So is there a snych/timing problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved:
For a looping process i need to start with:

```
var pyshell = new PythonShell('test.py',{scriptPath:"./", pythonOptions: ['-u']});
```

I hope this helps other, too!